# How does cocos2d CCMenu accesses private member variable of base class without any error?

Tags: objective-c

This is not a cocos2d question, but more about Objective-C question.

There're two classes CCNode and CCMenu.
CCNode is an ancestor of CCMenu.
CCMenu accesses a private member variable children_ of CCNode directly, but doesn't get any error (or warnings).

We noticed this problem when we tried to subclass CCMenu, and do similar thing accessing children_ in the derived class.
Xcode didn't throw any error when building for simulator, but it threw errors saying 'children_' undeclared. (which makes sense!)

So I'm really confused..
it doesn't look like any compiler setting related (cocos2d compiles without any problem for somehow.)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the CCNode header, `children_` doesn't appear to be private. The CCNode interface doesn't have any visibility modifiers, and the default is `@protected`, so that instance variable *should* be visible to subclasses of CCNode.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was @private.. so that's my mistake. Then, how can I explain the compile error of the CCMenu derived class? It still doesn't seem to make sense..

Comment: Hmm.. I noticed that this error happens if that children_ is accessed from a method that's not overridden. If I try to access this from an overridden method, then there's no error. I was expecting similar behavior to C++, but I guess it's not. Is this how @protected members supposed to work?

Comment: I'm getting confused now.. I wrote a simple base class & derived class, and it compiles fine. I don't know why that specific CCMenu derived class threw an error.. For more info, I've duplicated -(CCMenuItem *) itemForTouch: (UITouch *) touch (implementation too) in the derived class, and children_ gets error.

Comment: I'm getting this error as well from times to times, never managed to understand that behavior. It seems that inherited variable sometimes can't get accessed by subclasses. Even adding @protected don't do the trick.